# Firestore update with merge - how to overwrite a part of the document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

When updating a document in Firestore, I want to keep most of the document, but change one property which contains an object.

**What I have**

```
{
  name: "John Doe",
  email: "me@example.com",
  friends: {
     a: {...},
     b: {...},
     c: {...},
     d: {...},
     e: {...},
     f: {...},
  }
}
```

Now, I have a new friends object like `{x: ..., y: ..., z: ...}`

I want to overwrite the `friends` tree of my document, but keep all other fields.

**What I want it to look like**

```
{
  name: "John Doe",
  email: "me@example.com",
  friends: {
     x: {...},
     y: {...},
     z: {...},
  }
}
```

However, if I do a `firestore.doc(...).update({friends: {...}}, { merge: true })`

**What I currently get**

```
{
  name: "John Doe",
  email: "me@example.com",
  friends: {
     a: {...},
     b: {...},
     c: {...},
     d: {...},
     e: {...},
     f: {...},
     x: {...},
     y: {...},
     z: {...},
  }
}
```

I know that I can do two updates, i.e. delete the field and then set it again, or I can read the document, change the object and save it without merging.

But isn't there a smart way to overwrite an object (map) while keeping the rest of the document untouched?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference?authuser=0#update) method, you just need to call it without a merge option.

```
firestore.doc(...).update({friends: {...}})
```

---

Note that [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference?authuser=0#update) has two different signatures:

```
update(data: UpdateData)
```

and

```
update(field: string | FieldPath, value: any, ...moreFieldsAndValues: any[])
```

If the first argument you pass to the method is an object it will consider that you use the first signature and therefore you can pass only one argument. So doing

```
firestore.doc(...).update({friends: {...}}, { merge: true })
```

should generate the following error:

"*Error: Function DocumentReference.update() requires 1 argument, but was called with 2 arguments.*"

---

On the other hand, you could call it this way:

```
  firestore
    .collection('...')
    .doc('...')
    .update(
      'friends.c',
      'Tom',
      'email', 
      'mynew_email@example.com',
      'lastUpdate',
      firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    );
```

---

Finally, to be complete, note that if you do the following (passing **one** string)

```
  firestore
    .collection('...')
    .doc('...')
    .update(
      'a_string'
    );
```

you will get the following error

"*Error: Function DocumentReference.update() requires at least 2 arguments, but was called with 1 argument.*"

which makes sense :-)

Comment: Thanks - somehow I did not notice that it was possible to update a specific field of an object, this makes a lot of sense, so if I put a field path as first argument, and only overwrite that part of the document.

I also think I was a little confused about the `update` and `set` methods

So I guess, when I need to merge, I'll call a `set(.... {merge:true{})` and when I need to overwrite a specific field I'll call an `update("friends", {...})`